# How can I make Swift's String type conform to the CVarArgType protocol?

Tags: swift

The Swift protocol definition is empty:

```
public protocol CVarArgType {
}
```

The Apple documentation page doesn't list any required methods:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CVarArgType_Protocol/index.html

So I would expect this to work:

```
extension String : CVarArgType {

}
```

but I get a build error: **Protocol requires property '_cVarArgEncoding' with type '[Int]' (Swift.CVarArgType)**

Where does this requirement come from, given that the protocol definition is empty?

Moving forward if I implement the computed property:

```
extension String : CVarArgType {
    public var _cVarArgEncoding: [Int] {
        get {
            //What is expected to be returned here?
        }
    }
}
```

What is expected to be returned as an array of `Int`?

**Updated: Why do I need this?**

I have a protocol named Identifiable that my Core Data entity model classes conform to, I have an extension to this protocol with a couple of constraints to provide a function that uses the id value in an NSPredicate with format constructor which requires the CVarArgType.

```
public protocol Identifiable {
    typealias IdentityType: CVarArgType, Hashable
    var id: IdentityType { get }
}

extension Identifiable where Self: Findable, Self: NSManagedObject {

    static public func find(id: IdentityType, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self? {
        return find(NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", id), context: context)
    }

}

public extension Findable where Self: NSManagedObject {

    static public func find(predicate: NSPredicate?, context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Self? {
        let fetchRequest = fetchRequestForEntity(inContext: context)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        return try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest).first as? Self
    }

}
```

Comment: I see little practical value of this, there are better way to work with `va_list` argument. However, I think the question still has some merits as it explores the edge of the ObjectiveC-Swift integration. Encoding could refer to the [ObjectiveC type encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html). If you can explain what you want to do, we can help more

Comment: @CodeDifferent I've updated the question to provide more context

Comment: Can you not use the arrayArgument init of NSPredicate? - `init(format predicateFormat: String, argumentArray arguments: [AnyObject]?)`

Comment: No I get a build error `Value of type 'Self.IdentityType' does not conform to expected element type 'AnyObject'`

Comment: Your protocol doesn't inherit from NSObjectProtocol which should fix that. structs and enums probably don't mix well with NSPredicate anyway. Actually you may be able to cast it to an AnyObject as it is an NSManagedObject within this extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you should be trying to conform other types to them. The [Swift source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/97d8f50af4978e54289377a0bd205e71a34529a2/stdlib/public/core/VarArgs.swift) says:

> Note: the protocol is public, but its requirement is stdlib-private.
>   That's because there are APIs operating on CVarArg instances, but defining conformances to CVarArg outside of the standard library is not supported.

The stdlib is special in quite a few ways and hooks deeper into the build system than user code can. One example of this is that many stdlib functions can be inlined into your own code which is not currently possible across module boundaries in other cases.